# C# WinForms Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, c, winforms

If you remove the first 4 lines, then there are no errors.
But it is necessary to clean the weight and shape.
what's wrong with these 4 lines ?

```
 public void GameOver()
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(pipeTop.First().PB);
            this.Controls.Remove(pipeBottom.First().PB);

            pipeTop.Remove(pipeTop.First());
            pipeBottom.Remove(pipeBottom.First());

            this.Controls.Remove(bird.PB);
            this.Controls.Remove(ScoreBox);

            splashScreen.Image = fm.getCapture("gameover");
            splashScreen.Location = new Point(0, -500);

            startButton.Location = new Point(startButtonPozitionX, this.Size.Height + 150);
            statsButton.Location = new Point(statsButtonPozitionX, this.Size.Height + 150);

            this.Controls.Add(startButton);
            this.Controls.Add(statsButton);
            this.Controls.Add(splashScreen);

            GameOverAnimation.Start();
        }
```

Comment: In general, it's considered bad form to prefix `this.` where not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using First() which generates exception if the sequesnce or the collection has no elements, so you need to use FirstOrDefault and check for the return value to be != null before you use it.

So

1- Replace the first line to be :

```
var topPipe = pipeTop.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstPipe != null)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(firstPipe.PB);
}
```

2- Replace the second line to be :

```
var bottomPipe = pipeBottom.FirstOrDefault();
if (bottomPipe != null)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(bottomPipe.PB);
}
```

and so on...